# How do I find Ubuntu 20.04 icons for documentation

Tags: icons, simplescan

I am working on a handbook about scanning with simple-scan in Ubuntu 20.04.
I need to transfere some pictures from the screen to the manual written in Google docs. Some are fine .svg icons with rounded corners.
They need to be converted with CloudConvert on Google, but that shouldn't be a problem.
But I have a problem with finding this file: org.gnome.SimpleScan. I have it in the favorites menu, but where is it on the disk?
See what it looks like here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the search bar or the terminal to find files.

In the terminal you can use the commands `find`, `locate`, or `grep`.

To learn how to use these commands, you can review the manpages by adding `man` before each command.

For example:

```
man grep
```

Comment: I have tried the ways you name and I have found the file simple-scan.desktop with 13 lines of text. One line says: Icon=org.gnome.SimpleScan. Thats why I am searching for such a file. But maybe the search is wrong. I wish there were a way to send you a picture to show you what it looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the list of [installed files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/amd64/simple-scan/filelist) from *simple-scan* package locally by command like:

```
dpkg -L simple-scan | grep -E ".png$|.svg$"
```

It has a lot *SVG*s and *PNG*s.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this one [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmM3a.png). I found it on google. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AazW.jpg). Oh, it is another one. Since you have a screenshot you can use a graphical program e.g. 'Gwenview', 'Kolourpaint' or 'GIMP' to cut it out and save it as an .ico or .png or another format .